# Use Javascript to write src attribute as data-src, as page is loading

Tags: javascript, html, user-agent

> **Background:** Back in December I wanted my (custom) PHP page-building
>   engine to build a page one-way if the User Agent (UA) could handle
>   Javascript and a different way if the UA could not. To achieve this, I
>   needed to learn:
>
> *How to detect UA Javascript capability via PHP, prior to PHP building the page on-the-fly:*
>   [Detecting javascript in PHP, before PHP builds page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412949/detecting-javascript-in-php-before-php-builds-page)
>
> Thanks to some very helpful guidance from @skobaljic, @Abhi Beckert
>   and @GolezTrol, I learned that we can use Javascript to place
>   a session cookie which PHP will be able to query on all subsequent page
>   loads. Consequently, for every page after the first one, PHP will
>   *know* whether the UA is Javascript-capable or not
>
> So far, so good. Now I have reached the stage where I am no longer
>   building pages with PHP on-the-fly but pre-generating them and uploading
>   them to the server as static HTML documents.
>
> If you're still with me, you'll have guessed correctly this means I am
>   currently needing to pre-generate **two** static documents for each page -
>   *one* for the non-JS-capable UAs and *one* for the JS-capable UAs.
>   This isn't really ideal, hence my question below.

On the face of it, this looks like it ought to be a straightforward problem.

For Javascript-non-capable UAs, I want to build a document which contains lines like this:

```
<img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" />
```

For Javascript capable UAs, I want to build the same document which contains lines like this:

```
<img data-src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" />
```

*(for those who are curious, a javascript after `onload` converts all the data-src properties into src properties, following which many tens of server round-trips ensue but - crucially - **only after** the page has already substantially loaded).*

I have already achieved this via PHP and a session cookie (see **Background** above), but now, if it's possible, I want to execute the whole thing on the front-end.

How can I write an attribute into the `<img />` elements in the DOM as `src` by default but, additionally, (if javascript is available) prefix that attribute with `data-` so that it reads as `data-src`...

... such that...

**[IMPORTANT BIT]**

***If*** the UA is javascript-capable it will automatically and instantaneously write all instances of `src` as `data-src` *as the page is being downloaded by the UA*, so that after `onload` a javascript can then re-write all those instances of `data-src` as `src` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After nearly 3 days of head-scratching, I've finally cracked this.

**HEAD**

```
<head>

<script>
function initialiseImages() {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var section = scripts[scripts.length-1].parentNode;
        var images = section.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                        var src = images[i].getAttribute('src');
                        var datasrc = document.createAttribute('data-src');
                        datasrc.value = src;
                        images[i].setAttributeNode(datasrc);
                        images[i].removeAttribute('src');}}
</script>

</head>
```

**BODY**

```
<body>

<section>
<h2><img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" />Second Level Heading</h2>
<ul><li><img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" /></li></ul>
<script>initialiseImages();</script>
</section>

<section>
<h3>Third Level Heading</h3>
<ul>
<li><img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" /></li>
<li><img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" /></li>
<li><img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" /></li>
</ul>
<script>initialiseImages();</script>
</section>

</body>
```

---

**Update 1**

Thanks to Dave Walsh's article *Referencing a Script's own Tag* (http://davidwalsh.name/script-tag), I have re-written the first 3 lines of `function initialiseImages()`:

```
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var section = scripts[scripts.length-1].parentNode;
    var images = section.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

as a single line:

```
var images = document.currentScript.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

As far as I can tell, this defines `var images` fractionally faster and consequently catches more instances of `<img src=` before the UA sends a file-request to the server.

---

***Developer Notes follow...***

### Attempt #1 : Try to get Javascript to behave like PHP

I'm much more familiar with writing pages on-the-fly in PHP than with deploying Javascript, so my original intention was to find a way to use Javascript in a quasi-server-side manner to re-write the DOM instantaneously at the very moment it arrived:

> For Javascript-non-capable UAs, I want to build a document which
>   contains lines like this:
>
> ```
> <img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" />
> ```
>
> For Javascript capable UAs, I want to build the same document which
>   contains lines like this:
>
> ```
> <img data-src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" />
> ```

If such an approach is possible, I couldn't find a way to do it - and, to be fair, Javascript certainly isn't designed for instantaneously re-writing element properties the moment they arrive.

### Attempt #2 : Block image download via Javascript-added CSS

My second approach was to see if I could prevent image download via a line of CSS.

If I added that line with Javascript, only Javascript-capable UAs would be able to read the image-blocking style rule.

This didn't work either. It turns out, you can straightforwardly prevent CSS `background-images` from downloading, by applying `display:none;` to the **parent container** of the element which has the `background-image`. But the images I want to block (until after onload) are specifically `<img>s`, not `background-images` - and it turns out that as soon as the UA hits `<img src`, it runs off to the server to download the image.

### Attempt #3 : Inline Javascript in every `<img>`

Inline Javascript is pretty old-school, but @Darren Sweeney has already suggested an imaginative `<noscript>` solution, so I didn't want to automatically dismiss old-school. I thought about tackling the issue something like this:

```
<img src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" onEvent="initialiseImage();" />
```

The main issue I ran into here was I couldn't find any appropriate `onEvent`. I placed the `initialiseImage()` function in the `<head>` and then I wanted to have that function automatically fire every time the UA reached an `<img>` - but after extensive reading, I'm not sure that automatic execution inline is possible. (Perhaps someone can let me know in the comments below, if it is...)

Certainly, I could find no `onParse`.

The only element-specific `onEvent` that made sense was `onLoad`, which, in the case of an `<img>` (if I understand it correctly) downloads the `<img>` before it fires. So that was no good at all.

### Attempt #4 : Success at last!

Thus far:

1) From the start, the issue was that waiting until `window.onload` before using Javascript to rewrite every `<img src=` attribute was far too late;

2) I couldn't see a way to use Javascript to rewrite every `<img src=` instantly as it was downloading;

3) I couldn't see a way to use Javascript to rewrite every `<img src=` attribute just at the point the UA had parsed the `<img>`;

I reasoned that perhaps I could still use Javascript to rewrite every `<img src=` attribute at the moment the UA completed parsing each `<section>` containing each set of `<img>s`.

I am delighted to say I have tested the code above fairly thoroughly and it appears (so far) to work perfectly - long before the UA starts to request the `<img>` files from the server, the `<img src=` attribute has been replaced with a `<img data-src=` property and that request is no longer executed.

Answer (score 2):

Like this - not tested but should work:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var currentSrc = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
  imgs[i].setAttribute('src',''); // remove old src data 
  imgs[i].setAttribute('data-src','currentSrc');
}
```

All this does is add a new `data-src` attribute, and clears the current `src` (if needed)

Add just before the `</body>` tag

Comment: Thanks @Darren, that's almost exactly what I've got the reverse of (currently). I have written a script which takes all the `data-src` attributes in the initial DOM and rewrites them as `src` properties after `onload`. (Cue all the server-round trips...). But... I can't assume JS-capability by default, so what I actually need is for the Javascript-capable UA to first write those attributes as `data-src` *as the page is being accessed by the UA* - so the script probably needs to be in the `<head>` I'm thinking.

Comment: In summary, a non-JS-capable UA, simply reads the attribute as `src`, while a JS-capable UA, rewrites the attribute as `data-src` during page-load and then, after `onload`, rewrites all those `data-src` attributes (a second time) as `src` (cue all the server round-trips...)

Comment: I presume you're using something that reads `data-src` if JS enabled? Just add both. `data-src` will be ignored if no JS, and if there is JS, whatever you're using `data-src` for will find it.

Comment: You're right @Darren, `data-src` will be ignored if no JS. But... `src` *won't be ignored* if there is JS. And that's the behaviour I'm trying to tap into: if there is JS, don't try to load the images now, we'll do that after; if there isn't JS, well okay, you can start loading each image as you come across it (albeit, with all the pre-onload server round-trips, it will take the page a lot longer to appear).

Comment: Very frustrating. All I need (from one perspective) is a single .js statement (a statement which will be ignored by every UA which isn't JS-capable) which will inject the 5 character string variable `data-` immediately prior to every instance of `src` as the page is downloading... but I am unclear how to include .js variables inside HTML elements. So in the document `<head>`, I could have: `<script>var asyncImg = 'data-';</script>`... but then I'm unsure how to proceed from there.

Comment: But what is using the `data-src` attribute? If that's javascript, which I guess it is, it should be positioned AFTER the page loads anyway, you shouldn't mess with the DOM as it's rendering and AFAIK you actually can't, that would involve telling the browser engine to do something it doesn't want to do - can you explain exactly what is going on? What's using `data-src`

Comment: The `data-src` attribute is just an HTML5 `data-*` attribute (See: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). I want it there so that the page can load into all javascript-capable browsers without performing 101 round-trips to the server to collect all the (many) images as the page is downloading. This doesn't speed up the download of the page and all its assets, but it changes the order of the downloads (all DOM first, all images after) which feels faster (it really does!) and gives the user encouragement that the mobile site is responding quickly.

Comment: I could just have it so that all images on all generated pages initially contain `<img data-src="/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="My Image" />` and nothing else... but that does mean that wherever javascript is turned off or absent, there won't be any images displaying at all. And I'm working on the basis that all things considered, even when javascript is absent, a slower page with all images served is a better compromise than a faster page without any images. Not least when the (many) images actually represent the core content.

Comment: I've not got very far, trying to get the document's images to have a `data-src` attribute if the UA is javascript-capable or an `src` attribute if it is not, so I'm going to try to think of another way how I can arrange it so that the document's images don't download if the UA is javascript-capable and do download if it is not. I'm not sure how I might do this, but I'm imagining I might be able to achieve the effect I'm after by using javascript to append style rules...

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky way of doing it but all browsers (ie6+) support it:

```
<body>

    <noscript>
         <style>.img-hide { display: none; }</style>
    </noscript>

    <noscript><img src="/path/to/image1.jpg"></noscript>
    <img class="img-hide" data-src="/path/to/image1.jpg">

    <noscript><img src="/path/to/image2.jpg"></noscript>
    <img class="img-hide" data-src="/path/to/image2.jpg">

    <!-- etc etc etc -->

</body>
```

Comment: Haha. I love it. Thank you for this, @Darren. This likely won't be the solution I implement finally but it's always good to be reminded that `<noscript>` is always there as a last resort.

Comment: Right. I am going out for a run. It sometimes leads to inspiration. Thank you for all the time you've spent on this, this afternoon @Darren - very much appreciated.